# Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Type issue when using a function

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, types, async-await

I have a call I am making to my Firebase db to return a document to get data from:

```
                        final docRef = db
                            .collection("GearLockerItems")
                            .doc(itemIDList[index]);
                        var doc = await docRef.get();
                        final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                        String itemWeight = data['itemWeight'];
                        String itemWeightFormat = data['itemWeightFormat'];
```

After testing the code and knowing that it works, I wanted to create a function in order to clean up the code and make it easier to read. The function I created looks like this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getItem(
    itemIDList, index) async {
  final docRef = db.collection("Items").doc(itemIDList[index]);
  var doc = await docRef.get();
  final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

  return data;
}
```

And then I call the function back in my main code with:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> data = getGearLockerItemInStream(itemIDList, index);
```

But then when I try and use data as I did earlier to get the individual values like this:

```
String itemWeight = data['itemWeight'];
String itemWeightFormat = data['itemWeightFormat'];
```

I know get this error:

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'
```

I think the issue is with my types. I struggled on what type I was returning here in the function as I had never used `as Map<String, dynamic>;` before. The as concept was new to me. Its type casting I believe so I tried to use that type for the function but then struggled in the main code on the type for the data variable.

Comment: Are you using a future builder to resolve the promise/future before attempting to read the values assuming in a widget? The error says the type is still Future which means it's not resolved yet.

Comment: Its inside a stream builder that builds a list of CheckboxListTile. Then in the onChange for the CheckboxListTile I am calling this function to get a value from another document inside firestore.

Whats odd is the code works perfect before I put it into the function...

Comment: Gotcha! Need to use await in the main code too when you call getGearLockerItemInStream then it should be fine and onChange would become async.

Comment: @user1613360

this gives me an error:                             Future<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await getGearLockerItemInStream(itemIDList, index);


Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getGearLockerItemInStream(dynamic itemIDList, dynamic index)
Type: Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function(dynamic, dynamic) package:dont_forget_the_spoon/views/user_pack_list/functions.dart

A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

Comment: could you add the part you handle stream builder?

Comment: When you do the await it won't be a Future anymore the promise would be resolved. So this would be Map<String,dynamic> data = await getGearLockerItemInStream(itemIDList, index);

Comment: @user1613360 that resolved it! Thanks. I don't really understand fully though. If you post an answer with an explanation, I will accept it and be thankful for the learning experience!

Comment: This would be a great start https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should await for result because `getItem` is a async function, so change this:

```
await getGearLockerItemInStream(itemIDList, index);
```

because you do await the result wont be a Future anymore so you need to change  data type to Map<String, dynamic>>, so your final changes should be like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = await getGearLockerItemInStream(itemIDList, index);
```